# How To: Simple UIViewController w/ .xib using XCode15

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib, xcode15

I'm having issues creating a simple UIViewController in XCode15.

I want to create a .xib and accompanying .swift file as a controller.

Things seemed to have changed and I can't create a UIViewController with .xib.

I'm facing some error where it says the view outlet is not set.

I've tried everything.

Is there something wrong within the `didSelectRowAt` method?

Below are some screenshots of the latest attempt.

Any help (even step by step from scratch) would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it configured incorrectly. Actually, `CustomVC.swift` should be assigned to `File's Owner`. Then set the View as a referencing outlet for the File's Owner. You're assigning a `UIView` (which is CustomVC on xib file) to an instance of `UIViewController`.

Those steps are:

[image]

[image]

Right click then drag to View.

[image]

**Note**: I don't know why you're starting from scratch, but here's an alternative:

> XCode -> Command + N to create new file -> on iOS tab select `Cocoa Touch Class` -> Click `Also create XIB file`

Comment: I tried that and now have a longer error message. My UIViewController seems to have some outlet to some view set that is greyed out and I can't remove it. Oh, your example doesn't have a UIViewController and just a View. Let me try. I deleted the UIViewController I added to the .xib, and instead added just a View. Then I followed your instructions and it does seem to work. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, no big deal.

Comment: Oh, "Cocoa Touch Class" ... that helps a lot. I was wondering what I was doing wrong within the "File > New > File" menu. Been a while I suppose. I see now what I remember from previous version of XCode (i.e. "Also create XIB file"). Thanks again.